# Show that natural deduction proof can hold in this case

Tags: logic

> Let $a_1, a_2, b$ be propositional formulas where $\emptyset \vdash_{ND} (a_1 \implies a_2)$. Let $\sum$ be a set of formulas. Show that if $\sum \cup \{a_2 \} \vdash_{ND} b$ then also $\sum \cup \{a_1 \} \vdash_{ND} b$

Interesting problem.

Starting with the statement to prove, take $\sum$ and $a_1$ as premises. Using the given  $\emptyset \vdash_{ND} (a_1 \implies a_2)$, we use $\to e$ rule to get $a_2$.

And we are given $\sum \cup \{a_2 \} \vdash_{ND} b$ and have premises (now) $\sum, a_1, a_2$, so we can use $\sum, a_2$ to deduce $b$ thus conclusion holds.

Is this correct/formal enough?

Comment: Is it stated in the problem that $a_1$ and ∑ are premises? Or have you assumed this?
If you have assumed it, then you have only proven the result in the sub-context where $a_1$ and ∑ hold.

Answer (score 0):

So there is some proof $P$ of $b$ from $\Sigma$ and $a_2$ as premises.

Then adapt the proof: Assume $a_1$ first and we get $a_1 \implies a_2$ from no extra assumptions. The Modus Ponens rule allows us to cancel $a_1$ as a premise and replace it by $a_2$. Now follow proof $P$ to prove $b$.